# Can I declare a record positional parameter with a type defined inside the record?

Tags: c#, enums, record

Is it possible for record to be declared with positional parameters that include a type defined inside the record definition?

For example, can a variation of the following record declaration be made valid without moving the `enum` out of the record?

```
internal record class Character(string Name, GenderEnum Gender, int Age)
{
    public enum GenderEnum : byte { Male, Female, Other }
}
```

Comment: Despite getting an answer for this, I would advise against using nested types in general. It's very rarely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would follow the same rules as a type within a class. You need to fully qualify the type.

```
internal record class Character(string Name, Character.GenderEnum Gender, int Age)
{
    public enum GenderEnum : byte { Male, Female, Other }
}
```

```
var character = new Character("Joe", Character.GenderEnum.Male, 55);
Console.WriteLine(character);
// Character { Name = Joe, Gender = Male, Age = 55 }
```

Comment: Except it's not required in a regular class. You can use the name unqualified.

Comment: Probably because you don't need to use the `Character.` qualifier when you're within the type's curly braces. Record parameters are before it.

Comment: That makes sense, although it feels buggy. Anyway, they're talking about adding support for `nameof` in method attributes to allow it to be used on parameter names. Maybe that name binding scope will be extended to allow this, too.